# Seeding Nested Data with EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.2 ModelBuilder

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have an existing database which we are upgrading and migrating to a new `EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.2` Solution.

The existing database is quite badly designed, but has a large dataset I need to port over to the new model.

The current model I have is as follows (reduced for brevity);

```
public class Company 
{
    /*reduced for brevity*/

    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public IList<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class Address 
{
    /*redcued for brevity*/

    public IList<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }  
}

public class Contact 
{
    /*reduced for brevity*/ 

    public int? AddressId { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

The current data set contains enough information to set up the following (currently read from a CSV file);

```
Company
Company.Address
Company.Contact - singular
Company.Contact.Address
```

I have the following `.HasData` which is seeded in the `OnModelCreating` method;

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>(e =>
{
    e.HasData(new
    {
        Id = company.ID
    });

    e.OwnsOne(a => a.Address).HasData(new
    {
        CompanyId = company.ID,
        Address1 = company.Address
    });

    e.OwnsMany(c => c.Contacts).HasData(new
    {
         CompanyId = company.ID         
         //How to add in the address data here?
    });    
 });
```

I have tried to add in the following;

```
e.OwnsMany(c => c.Contacts).HasData(new
{
     CompanyId = company.ID         ,
     Address = new Address
     {
         Address1 = company.DirectorAddress,
     }
});
```

However this throws the following error;

> System.InvalidOperationException: The type 'Address' cannot be marked as owned because a non-owned entity type with the same name already exists.

Which to confirm is generated whether the `Company.Contact.Address` Entity is present or not. So I assume this is down to the fact I have my foreign key the other way arouns (i.e. `Company.AddressId` as opposed to `Address.CompanyId`).

Would it be confirm the following;

1. How can I reference the `Address` to the `Company` without having a specific Id?
2. How can I add in the `Company.Contact.Address` to the 1st Contact added to the list?